# Mouse Hover on Bullet Chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this Bullet Chart with metrics (satisfactory, bad, target, measure). 
I want to put a certain value in each of this metrics and I aim to see the values by mouse hovering

here is the Code :

```
         {bulletchartdata.map(
        (item,index)=>{
            return(

        <div className="satisfactory"style={{backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',height:20,width:item.satisfactoryVal,position:'absolute'}}>           
            <div className="badcolor"style={{backgroundColor:'#d8d6d6',height:20,width:item.badVal,position:'relative'}}></div>
                <div className="target"style={{backgroundColor:'#000000',height:16,width:1,left:item.symbolMarker,position:'relative',top:-18}}></div>
                    <div className="measure"style={{backgroundColor:'#8c8c8c',height:5,width:item.performanceVal,position:'relative',top:-29}}></div>


        </div>

            );

        }
    )}
```

Hope anyone could help me with my problem Thanks :D
[here is the bullet chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAWZK.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id -"new" className="satisfactory"onmouseover = "something()"style={{backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2',height:20,width:item.satisfactoryVal,position:'absolute'}}>

function something(){
    document.getElementbyID("new");
    new.value = "my value"
}
```

should work give it a try?